# How to copy folder structure without files into a new directory on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: terminal, rsync, copy

I've looked this up and tried everything using rsync and involving find ., but keep getting errors. Using rsync I get "rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3)", and using find . all my subfolders I want to copy say "read-only file system." I've seen that this is a common issue with Catalina, however. Is there an alternate solution that will allow me to copy just the folder structure (without the files) into a new directory? Thanks!

Comment: If you would format your post properly, it would be easier to read...

Answer (score 1):

Say you `cd`ed to the folder you want to copy, and the destination is `~/kiki`.

You can just run

> find . -type d -exec mkdir -p ~/kiki/{} \;

and you're done.

Comment: When I do that, it lists all the directories and says "read-only file system" (this is when the path is relative to my current directory -- ie. /../dir/. When I do it as the full path from home, it runs without error but doesn't create the new folders

Comment: For the "relative to current directory" case, you mention /.../dir/. However, starting with a / makes it absolute, not relative. So you will land somewhere in root directory, which is read-only in Catalina.

Comment: To give you a full example, say the folder structure you want to copy is in /Users/xx/orig and you want to create the duplicate folder structure in /Users/xx/new. Then you can run `cd /Users/xx/orig` and then `find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /Users/xx/new/{} \;` Replace xx with your user name.

Comment: I copied exactly that, but it still gave me "read only file system"

Comment: Maybe you can post a screen shot of your Mac Terminal window (using Shift+Cmd+5) - I might be able to further diagnose things based on that.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to attach an image, but I'll type it out. After I type in the line, it returns "mkdir: /path/to/file/subfolder: Read-only file system" It does this for each folder in the directory

Comment: The reason I asked for the screenshot is I wanted to know what the /path/to/file/subfolder actually is. If you're using `/path/to/...`, it will try to put it under `/path`, which is part of the so-called root directory, which cannot be changed for security reasons. That's why you get that read-only message. If the path starts with the tilde character (`~`), it means it's your home directory, i.e. a place you have write access to. That's why I used `~/kiki` in my example: It's the subdir named kiki inside your home dir. Please let the path name start in `~`, and NOT in `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try without rsync:

The following will list all directory structure without files:

```
# find . -type d
```

to add a prefix for each input line (not really useful as standalone command)

```
# sed 's/^/mkdir /'
```

put it together:

```
# find . -type d | sed 's/^/mkdir /'
```

creating the script, so you can create the Directory structure later:

```
# find . -type d | sed 's/^/mkdir /' > DirStructure.sh
# chmod +x DirStructure.sh
```

then, run the script "./DirStructure.sh" in order to create the directory tree wherever you want, whenever you want.